# Persistent Logging in Gnome-Shell-Extension development?

Tags: gtk, clutter, gnome-3, gnome-shell, gfs

I'm trying around with the Javascript-based bindings to build an own Gnome-Shell-Extension which just embeds an webkitview.

But the following 3 lines let completely crash the gnome-shell (top panel disappears, need to re-login to start it again). therefore no way to look into the "Errors"-tab of LookingGlass to figure out, what was wrong.

```
WebKit = imports.gi.WebKit;
GtkClutter = imports.gi.GtkClutter;
Main.panel._rightBox.add(new GtkClutter.Actor({contents: new WebKit.WebView()}));
```

Is there any way to get some infos what's going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

you cannot embed a WebKitGtk WebView inside gnome-shell, or any other GTK widget, include GtkClutterEmbed; this is actually a limitation of GTK.

if you want to embed a WebKitGtk WebView one option is to use a separate process, get the XID of the GtkWindow and use a ClutterX11TexturePixmap actor to display it inside an extension. you'll have to pass events from the Clutter actor to your application as well. you can use some form of IPC, like D-Bus, to pass the XID and the events.